# How do I download a website with Chrome Headless from the command line?

Tags: bash, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

Can I use Headless Chrome/Chromium as a substitute for `curl` or `wget` from Bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `--dump-dom` flag:

```
chrome --headless --dump-dom <url>
```

or if you're using Chromium on Linux

```
chromium-browser --headless --dump-dom <url>
```

will dump the HTML contents of the page to your terminal (ie. to stdout), just like `curl`.

See the official post [Getting Started with Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome).

On Windows you might also need to pass `--disable-gpu` to those commands.