# chrome headless dump dom flag prints nothing to stdout

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

Executing headless chrome with the flag --dump-dom or --dump-html yields nothing on stdout. Does anyone know why?

Commands I have tried, with no output:

```
"c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --dump-dom --disable-gpu https://www.chromestatus.com/
"c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --dump-html --disable-gpu https://www.chromestatus.com/
"c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --dump-html https://www.chromestatus.com/
"c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --dump-dom https://www.chromestatus.com/
"c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --dump-dom --incognito https://www.chromestatus.com/
```

Removing the --headless option will open the chrome window, no problem.

```
"c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --dump-html https://www.chromestatus.com/
```

I can screenshot with --headless chrome no problem.

```
"c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --screenshot=D:\test.png --disable-gpu --window-size=320,568 https://www.chromestatus.com --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1"
```

[image: screenshot]

Python script showing process is successfully run.

```
In [1]: import subprocess

In [2]: cp = subprocess.run( '"c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --dump-dom --disable-gpu https://www.chromestatus.com/', shell=True)

In [3]: cp.stderr

In [4]: cp.returncode
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: cp.args
Out[5]: '"c:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" --headless --dump-dom --disable-gpu https://www.chromestatus.com/'

In [6]: cp.stderr

In [7]: cp = subprocess.run( '"c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.chromestatus.com/', shell=True)
```

Information

- chrome version: 99.0.4844.51 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Windows version 20H2 (10942.1415)
- Also I have multiple google chrome sync accounts. I dunno if the will interfere.

[image: multiple chrome accounts]

Reference:

- https://blog.darkthread.net/blog/headless-chrome/
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome
- [How do I download a website with Chrome Headless from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614488/how-do-i-download-a-website-with-chrome-headless-from-the-command-line)